# How to save image to iOS camera roll using default react-native Share component

Tags: ios, react-native, share

I cannot manage to get the **Save Image** button menu sharing a remote image through default react-native [Share](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/share) component.

My code looks like:

```
import { Share } from 'react-native'
Share.share({url: 'https://i.imgur.com/I5DFV.jpg'})
```

Expected:
[image: 1]

Current:
[image: 2]